# Elpy Configuration...Setting Up a Virtual Environment and Pip Conflic with Conda? Need hand holding

Tags: microsoft-windows, elpy, anaconda-mode

Full disclosure: I installed anaconda and set it to the path variable. After I did this I was able to access elpy-config which I was not able to (see my [prior question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59962/trouble-installing-elpy-totally-newb-to-both-emacs-and-programming)). I still pretty much have no idea why this worked and what I'm doing right or wrong.

My three questions:

**1.** When I type command `M-x pyvenv` I get a message saying `Can't find a workon home directory, set $WORKON_HOME.` How do I actually do this without screwing up the existing paths?

**2.** How do I setup a virtual environment? I have trouble understanding this conceptually and I get confused as to what I'm actually doing when following instructions.

**3.** I read that having pip and conda simultaneously can bring issues when trying to install various packages. The warning tells me that I need pip...but do I?

````
Elpy Configuration 

Emacs.............: 26.3
Elpy..............: 1.34.0
Virtualenv........: None
Interactive Python: python . (c:/Users/Robby Parliament/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (c:/Users/Robby Parliament/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe 3.8.3 (c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe)
 Jedi.............: 0.17.1
 Rope.............: 0.17.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.3
 Yapf.............: 0.30.0
 Black............: Not found
Syntax checker....: flake8.exe (c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/flake8.exe)```
````

Followed by:

```
Warnings

You have not activated a virtual env. While Elpy supports this, it is
often a good idea to work inside a virtual env. You can use M-x
pyvenv-activate or M-x pyvenv-workon to activate a virtual env.

Elpy could not connect to Pypi (or at least not quickly enough) and
check if the python packages were up-to-date. You can still try to
update all of them:

[Update python packages]

Pip doesn't seem to be installed in the dedicated virtualenv created
by Elpy (c:/Users/Robby Parliament/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv). This may
prevent some features from working properly (completion,
documentation, reformatting, ...). You can try reinstalling the
virtualenv. If the problem persists, please report on Elpy's github
page.

[Reinstall RPC virtualenv]

The black package is not available. Commands using this will not work.
```

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:**
If you haven't already done so, go ahead and create a new `conda` environment. Let us say
we want to create an anaconda environment with name `py38` which uses `python 3.8`. Execute
the following in an (Anaconda prompt)

```
conda create --name py38 python=3.8
```

*Note:* You can get to an anaconda prompt by clicking on the windows button and then
searching for *anaconda prompt*

Now we need to find out where the previous `conda create` command created your
virtual environment. In the `anaconda prompt` execute:

```
conda info --envs
```

This command will show you a list of locations where your `virtual environments` are
located. (including the base environment that anaconda creates by default). The output
will look something like the following:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
py38                     C:\Users\robbie\.conda\envs\py37
```

Now everytime you create a virtual environment it will (by default) go inside of
`C:\Users\robbie\.conda\envs` unless you tell it otherwise by messing
with `config` files. Since you are getting started I suggest you go with
the default location.

**Step 2**
We can now set the `WORKON_HOME` to be this location. Put the following
in your `init.el` (obviously change it to the actual output you got previously)

```
;; workon home
(setenv "WORKON_HOME" "C:/Users/robbie/.conda/envs/")
```

Now `re-start` emacs and run

```
M-x: pyvenv-workon [TAB]
```

Your previously created virtual environment will now show up here. Choose
your desired virtual environment (in this case `py38`) now your `Emacs`
session uses this virtual environment. If you now run `elpy-config` you
will see that the `python` entry in your `elpy` configuration has changed
to something like:

```
Python...........: python 3.8.1 (c:/Users/robbie/.conda/envs/py38/python.exe)
```

If you'd rather use the `base` anaconda.

```
M-x: pyvenv-activate [RET]
```

then give the location of your `base` environment. In your case
`c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3`. I suggest you heed elpy's
advise here and always work inside a virtual environment.

As for your third question `conda` and `pip` can co-exist
peacefully. If you want more information see this
[blogpost](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/)
by Jake VanderPlas.

**Notes**:

1. You can get more information about (for example) `conda create` by
   running in the `anaconda prompt`.

```
conda create --help
```

2. In windows you must run these commands in the `anaconda prompt` rather
   than your regular windows `cmd prompt`.

Comment: Hi - so first off thank you for your response. Secondly, it appears to me that I have a more fundamental issue with emacs that I must resolve before further tinkering with virtual environments. I'm going to post a new question I'd love if you could take a look